# Subversion and DBUnit - How to download a specific snapshot version

Tags: unit-testing, svn, testing, configuration, dbunit

I posted a question to the DBunit mailing list about an error I see when I compile my program. One of the response I get is shown below:

> Please try 2.4.9-SNAPSHOT (you will have to build from source;
>   snapshots are not currently pre-built). I believe commit 1209 fixes
>   the problem you are experiencing:

I looked at the DBunit project and I can't figure out how to download this specific version. 
I tried this command but it comes back with a `Does not exist error`

```
svn checkout https://dbunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dbunit/trunc/2.4.9-SNAPSHOT dbunit
```

I think the command is correct because if I try a release that does exist it does work. For example the following command works

```
svn checkout https://dbunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dbunit/tags/dbunit-2.4.8 dbunit
```

Looking at the online code browser I can't see an entry with the tag I want. See Example at http://dbunit.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dbunit/

Does this mean that the `2.4.9-SNAPSHOT` does not exist or am I doing it wrong?

Also, what does the SNAPSHOT label mean at the end of the release version? I have seen this used quite a lot but not really sure what it means.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the source code in specified revision:

```
$ svn co https://dbunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dbunit/trunk dbunit -r 1209
$ cd dbunit
$ mvn clean install
```

The `2.4.9-SNAPSHOT` version should appear in your repository when the build finishes. However I encounter some problems while building it, the `com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0` cannot be found. Consult library developers how to fix this.